# Java Memory Leak using Config

Tags: java, memory-leaks

We're using this below code to read config values from XML. I think it can cause a memory leak.

```
   // simulated code
   class ConfigReader {

      void matchPlanIDs() {
           ConfigurationItem[] items = ConfigurationHelper.getConfiguration("PLAN_IDS");
           // do something with here in for loop by reading from 
           // items[i].getTagVlue()...;  

           return;
      }
   }
```

Is items[] having reference to  ConfigurationHelper.getConfiguration("PLAN_IDS") at the end of the method execution and can't be garbage collected in one cycle? Is this a strong reference?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Are you sure it is a ***memory leak***? Or are you simply consuming too much memory?

Comment: what do u do here 
    // do something with here in for loop by reading from
? check if your class is holding referenecs to items in any way?

Comment: @HefferWolf: It was a doubt that I had. Thanks for the clarifications. If items[] is declared as class-level (static) variable and initialized to hold elements from config, this will optimize the code since values are not read for each and every thread execution but only the first time. Right?

Comment: If you set the whole line as static class attribute, the configuration will only be run if the class is loaded (which usually is only once, but don't count on it).

Answer (score 1):

By itself,

```
void matchPlanIDs() {
     ConfigurationItem[] items = ...
   return;
  }
```

Cannot cause a memory leak. Of course `items` will be garbage collected.

By the way, the `return` at the end is also pointless.

If you think `ConfigurationHelper.getConfiguration(...)` is causing a memory leak, try to verify this by a simple example. If indeed you notice an abnormal behavior, probably it would be better to submit a bug report to the author of `ConfigurationHelper`. However, I suspect this case in unlikely, and I suspect your memory consumption problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The items instance can immediately garbage collected after the end of the method execution as nothing is holding a reference to it. This doesn't have any memory leak potential. During execution of the method the array might consume a lot of memory though and might cause a Full GC if your GC isn't properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [free software tools that can be used to detect memory leaks](http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source).